# How do I pipe a file from S3 to the client in Uint8List format in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter

I am currently working on a Api just to get to know Node.js, as I am currently learning it.

I successfully created a route for uploading an mp3 file into an s3 bucket, but when I try to fetch a file from S3 in Uint8List format, I don't get the results I want. (Flutter requires me to send an Uin8List, if this is not a good solution I can also convert it into an Ui8List on the client side)

I am able to create a Readable stream, and when the stream receives chunks it logs it into the console. But I am not quite sure how I can send the data back to the client in buffers, I am only able to send the data in one big list but ofcourse for efficiency this is not the best option.

Anyone able to help me? This is the code is currently have:

```
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    
    AWS.config.update(
        {
            accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: AWS_REGION
        }
    );
    
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();   

 

router.get('/assets/:fileKey', auth, async function (req, res, next) {
        try {
            const fileKey = req.params.fileKey;
    
            const options = {
                Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: fileKey,
            };
    
            const chunks = [];
    
            const getAsBytes = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const readStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
    
                readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    // console.log('-------new data received--------')
                    // console.log(chunk);
                    chunks.push(chunk);
                    // res.write(chunk);
                });
    
                readStream.on('error', reject)
    
                readStream.on('end', resolve);
            }).catch((err) => next(err));
    
            await getAsBytes;
    
            res.write(Uint8Array.from(chunks));
            res.end();
    
    
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    });
```

When I try to pipe the readstream I get a response full of question marks and weird symbols..

Comment: did you try piping the response this way.
```res.attachment('filename');  
await s3.getObject(options).createReadStream().pipe(res)```
This will stream data from S3 directly to the client.

Comment: @vicki I tried, but awaiting a createWrirteStream is not possible, also it gives me a response in the form of this:

Comment: @vicki Okay not able to send the characters through Stackoverflow but it does not send data I can do anything with as it is just a big string with all sorts of weird characters and question marks

Comment: Why using an array of bytes? Why not do ```chunks += chunk``` instead of ```chunks.push(chunk)``` and then convert that stream to an uint8array?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -> the chunk is actually a buffer so you need to convert that buffer to actual data using `.toString()`

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: AWS_REGION
});
        
var s3 = new AWS.S3();   
    
router.get('/assets/:fileKey', auth, async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const fileKey = req.params.fileKey;
        
    const options = {
      Bucket: AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: fileKey,
    };
        
    const chunks = [];
        
    const getAsBytes = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const readStream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
        
      readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        // console.log('-------new data received--------')
        // console.log(chunk);
        chunks.push(chunk.toString());
        // res.write(chunk);
      });
        
      readStream.on('error', reject)
        
      readStream.on('end', resolve);
    }).catch((err) => next(err));
        
    await getAsBytes;
        
    res.write(Uint8Array.from(chunks));
    res.end();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```